# Why is this SCSS selector not working

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
   <span class="holder__title">TITLE ONE</span>
</div>
<div class="holder">
   <span class="holder__title">TITLE TWO</span>
</div>
<div class="holder">
   <span class="holder__title">TITLE THREE</span>
</div>
```

Now, I want to modify `TITLE TWO` and `TITLE THREE` `spans` only and leave the first as it is, but I cannot get it to work. This is what I have tried:

```
.holder {
   &:not(:first-child) {
      &__title {
        display:none; // just to test
     }
  }
}
```

and

```
.holder {
  &:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {

    &__title {
      display:none; // just to test
    }
  }
}
```

It works ok in developer tools, but when I enter it in `.scss` file and compile nothings happens. Like selectors do not even get targeted.

How can I resolve this please?

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to class as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. `__title` is missing `.holder` from the front of it.

Comment: Sorry, what is missing what?

Comment: A class selector starts with `.`. Your class is `holder__title`. You must have deleted the `.holder` from the front of `__title` by accident.

Comment: No, I am following BEM methodology. http://getbem.com/ No need to use `.holder__title` if `.holder` is already in the parent. Reusability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` translates into ***existing selector at this exact point***. Which means that this

```
.holder {
   &:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
     ...some-rule...
     &__title {
       ...other-rule...
     }
   }
 }
```

translates into this CSS:

```
.holder:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  ...some-rule...
}
.holder:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)__title {
  ...other-rule...
}
```

If you're really keen on doing it properly, you should put `.holder` inside a variable, which doesn't break BEM (you're able to change it from only one place):

```
$name: '.holder';
#{$name} {
   &:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
     ...some-rule...
     #{$name}__title {
       ...other-rule...
     }
 }
```

which translates into this:

```
.holder:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  ...some-rule...
}
.holder:nth-child(n+2):nth-child .holder__title {
  ...other-rule...
}
```

Comment: Hi. No, I am trying to target `__title` inside the `.holder`. And all this with BEM methodology. I need to target the 2nd and third only.

Comment: @JohnSam In that case you're using `nth-child` wrong. Are you sure `:nth-child(n + 2):nth-child(-n+3)` selects what you think it selects? I'll make a fiddle for you shortly.

Comment: Yes, it does. In my Developer tools it does. Please do, thanks. Also, the one with `:first-child` is correct in my DEV tools..

Comment: Ok. I have your answer. Hold on a minute, please

Comment: The answer of @Cata John above is the closest, but it is breaking BEM. I am trying to keep the methodolgy intact, as it is used in entire document.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your final CSS should look like, so you might actually tell us that, it would be easier to tell you how to get the result if we know the result. But I got your problem and I think I addressed it in the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165788/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-johnsam).

Comment: Let's, I'm there.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to write is invalid SCSS. Remember, the & always refers to the parent selector when nesting.

So your SCSS

```
.holder {
   &:not(:first-child) {
      &__title {
        display:none; // just to test
     }
  }
}
```

will translate to this CSS which is invalid:

```
.holder:not(:first-child) .holder:not(:first-child)__title {
   display:none; // just to test
}
```

A solution would be:

```
.holder {
   &:not(:first-child) {
      .holder__title {
        display:none;
     }
  }
}
```

Even though, this will break the BEM notation. Still, i will leave this here in case no better answer shows up.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution to use nested SCSS with a pseudo class like `:not()` without breaking BEM methodology would be:

```
.holder {
  $holder: &;

   &:not(:first-child) {
      #{$holder}__title {
        display:none;
     }
  }
}
```